# GraphQL querying in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, graphql

I am using GraphQL query plugin in Unity and I am able to Introspect as well. What the problem I am facing is adding set of arguments to pass on this query. How do I pass the arguments shown in the query below such as the "ID" and "Type_ID":

```
{
  MyData(
    ID: "12abr23",
    Type_ID: "PQ56C43"
  ) {
    name
    time
  }
}
```

```
public GraphApi Graph;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start () {
        GetDetails ();
    }

    public async void GetDetails () {
        GraphApi.Query query = Graph.GetQueryByName ("MyData", GraphApi.Query.Type.Query);
        UnityWebRequest request = await Graph.Post (query);
        query.SetArgs (new { ID= "12abr23" new { Type_ID = "PQ56C43"  }}); //Facing issue here
        JSONNode itemsData = JSON.Parse (request.downloadHandler.text);
        var parseJSON = JSON.Parse (request.downloadHandler.text);
        Debug.Log ("PARSE: " + HttpHandler.FormatJson (request.downloadHandler.text));

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since Args declares the objects, I had to only separate them under {}. So the result becomes:

```
query.SetArgs (new { ID= "12abr23", Type_ID = "PQ56C43" });
```